# typed.js with bootstrap is not working for some reason when included together? Works separately

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, typed.js

I am trying to integrate typed.js in my bootstrap webpage. However, it just prints out plain text and there is no animation whatsoever. However, when i have the typed.js file in a separate html file, it works perfectly well. Any ideas on what might be going on? I am currently using the example given on its official website as a test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bhimesh S. Chauhan</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/B.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myweb2.css">
    <link rel="css/bootstrap.min.css" href="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- Get jQuery -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/typed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--<div id="bkg-im">
        <img src="image/chess.jpg"></img>
    </div>-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="myweb.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-king"></span> BHIMESH</a>
            </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower"></span> About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-queen"></span> Resume</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-knight"></span> Some Interesting Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bishop"></span> Read My Thoughts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> Interesting Ideas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></span> Write To Me!</a></li>
                </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script>
        $(function(){

          $("#typed").typed({
            // strings: ["Typed.js is a <strong>jQuery</strong> plugin.", "It <em>types</em> out sentences.", "And then deletes them.", "Try it out!"],
            stringsElement: $('#typed-strings'),
            typeSpeed: 30,
            backDelay: 500,
            loop: false,
            contentType: 'html', // or text
            // defaults to false for infinite loop
            loopCount: false,
            callback: function(){ foo(); },
            resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }
        });

          $(".reset").click(function(){
                            $("#typed").typed('reset');
                            });

          });

          function newTyped(){ /* A new typed object */ }

          function foo(){ console.log("Callback"); }

        </script>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style>
        /* code for animated blinking cursor */
        .typed-cursor{
            opacity: 1;
            font-weight: 100;
            -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
            -moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
            -ms-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
            -o-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
            animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
        }
    @-keyframes blink{
        0% { opacity:1; }
        50% { opacity:0; }
        100% { opacity:1; }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes blink{
        0% { opacity:1; }
        50% { opacity:0; }
        100% { opacity:1; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes blink{
        0% { opacity:1; }
        50% { opacity:0; }
        100% { opacity:1; }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes blink{
        0% { opacity:1; }
        50% { opacity:0; }
        100% { opacity:1; }
    }
    @-o-keyframes blink{
        0% { opacity:1; }
        50% { opacity:0; }
        100% { opacity:1; }
    }
    </style>

</head>




<body>

    <div class="container" id="tile">
        <div id="first_tile">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail" id="tile_one">
                    <img src="image/rook_outline.png" alt="image source">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="second_tile">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <div id="image2">
                        <img src="image/second_image.png" alt="image source">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="third_tile">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="image/king_outline.gif" alt="image source">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fourth_tile">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <div id="image4">
                        <img src="image/fourth_image.png" alt="image source">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fifth_tile">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="image/knight_outline.png" alt="image source">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="sixth_tile">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <div id-="image6">
                        <img src="image/sixth_image.png" alt="image source">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="seventh_tile">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <div id="image7">
                        <img src="image/queen_outline.png" alt="image source">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="eighth_tile">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <div id="image8">
                        <img src="image/eight_image.png" alt="image source">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ninth_tile">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="image/bishop_outline.png" alt="image source">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tenth_tile">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <div id="image10">
                        <img src="image/tenth_image.png" alt="image source">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap">
        <h1 class="h1">Typed.js</h1>

        <div class="type-wrap">
            <div id="typed-strings">
                <span>Typed.js is a <strong>jQuery</strong> plugin.</span>
                <p>It <em>types</em> out sentences.</p>
                <p>And then deletes them.</p>
                <p>Try it out!</p>
            </div>
            <span id="typed" style="white-space:pre;"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="links">
            <a href="http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js">View original demo</a> | <a href="http://www.mattboldt.com">View mattboldt.com</a> | <a href="http://www.twitter.com/atmattb">Complain to Matt about how awful this is</a>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div id="the_footer" align="center">
        <p>&#169; ESARC Bhimesh</p>
    </div>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your code? Read this please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The typed.js code is copied from https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/ for testing purpose

Comment: This actually worked for me when I put it in a JSFiddle. My only guesses would be 1) You've included jQuery *after* the Bootstrap JS instead of before (and you add it again at the bottom of the page) and 2) You've got some HTML in the head tag instead of the body.